# how to disable touch in Quintus?

Tags: html, input, html5-canvas, touch, game-engine

hi i'm new in web games development and trying to build card game using the `Quintus` game engine i have object called card i can touch and drag it in the screen but i want just to touch and drag it one time but i can't figure out how to disable the touch after i dragged the card and i try to Google it but no luck my code :

```
Q.Sprite.extend("Card", {


init: function(p){

    this._super(p,{
        asset: "Queen_OF_Hearts.png",
        x: Q.el.width / 2,
        y: Q.el.height - 120
    });

   this.on("drag");
   this.on("touchEnd");
},

drag: function(touch) {
   this.p.dragging = true;
   this.p.x = touch.origX + touch.dx;
   this.p.y = touch.origY + touch.dy;
 },

touchEnd: function(touch) {
   this.p.dragging = false;
   // put a line on the screen if the card pass it put the card in the new position if not put the card in the orginal(old) postion
   if(touch.origY + touch.dy > Q.el.height - 200) { //define the line that the card should pass if the amount of draged > the screen line in Q.el.height - 200
       // put the card in the same old postion if is not pass the line
       this.p.x = touch.origX;
       this.p.y = touch.origY;

    } else {
        // put the card if it pass the line in the new postion  
        this.p.x = Q.el.width / 2;
        this.p.y = Q.el.height - 280;

    }
}
});
```

so in the else statement in the `touchEnd` i'm trying to do some thing like that

```
this.p.touch = false;
```

but is not working so any help and if you please mention any sources for `Quintus` documentation or book or any good resources for `Quintus` thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable the touch event completely, add this:

```
Q.untouch();
```

If you want only for one sprite/element:

```
touchEnd: function(touch) {
    touch.obj.off('drag');
    touch.obj.off('touchEnd');
}
```

Where did I find this? [Here](https://github.com/cykod/Quintus/tree/master/lib)